# How do I add an event handler for when a thread finishes in MFC?

Tags: multithreading, mfc

At the moment, I am using `WaitForSingleObject` to wait for a sub-task thread to complete. Unfortunately, this causes my GUI to lock up. What I would like to do instead, is set a handler (in the GUI thread) that will be called after the sub-task thread is complete. Is there another function for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to let the last thing that your thread does be posting a custom message to your window. Then handle that as a regular message using MFC's message map. If you cannot change the thread code, you can create a new thread that waits for your thread and then sends the message.

As you already noticed, it is not a good idea to lock up the GUI thread...

Edit: Posting the message is done using the PostMessage function as pointed out by Hans in the comments.

Comment: PostMessage, not sending a message.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I agree with you that this is the correct method to use. Sloppy choice of words on my part and I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Could also have a look at MsgWaitForMultipleObjects (or MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx).
These allow a thread to wait for event handles and service windows messages (examine the return value to see what causes the call to return). Examples of usage should be available via a goodle search.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684245(VS.85).aspx